# How do I check if paypal sandbox is experiencing outages?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to do some very simple test payments with the rest-api-sdk-php and so far everything has been so SKETCHY!

First attempt worked fine, second attempt the redirect to paypal takes forever (like five minutes) so I assume.

Next attempt I get an internal server error on paypals site.

Next attempt I get redirected to the 1995 version of paypal (doing exactly the same thing as before)

Next attempt I get some big red warning with a page long list of errors on the 1995 paypal site.

Trying again takes at least 10 minutes to process and redirect to my site with a 400 error.

Now on my last attempt it worked fine...

**So my question is, aside from asking paypal by telephone, how do I find out if their sandbox servers are crashed or experiencing issues?**

Comment: FYI, sandbox has been having issues and has been unusable for me for around 12 hours now.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the confirmation, I also found a bug in my code which was contributing to errors, but there definitely were some issues with paypal's sandbox servers.